# Login using webpage then return to native app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have no knowledge of xcode yet but am about to dig in.

We are creating an app for our web service. We want 99% of the app to be native using xcode functions to get json responses from the server, but we want to use our website's own custom login page first to establish the session.

The flow would be like this:

1. Open app.
2. App requests json response from php file on server.
3. If user not logged in, the php file redirects app to actual login page on server.
4. User logs in, then is redirected back to original php file to get json response.
5. App retrieves json response and continues to menu page.

Is this possible? I'm not sure it is because once we've loaded the html for the login page, the app isn't waiting for the json response anymore.

I've thought about this solution:

1. Open app.
2. App requests json response from php file on server.
3. If user not logged in, the php file returns json response saying not logged in.
4. App sends user to login page to login.
5. Meanwhile, app asynchronously checks every few seconds if user is logged in yet.
6. User logs in and is redirected to a spinning graphic page.
7. One of the asynchronous logged in checks gets positive response back and takes user away from website (spinning graphic page) and displays native app menu.
8. Asynchronous log in checks cease.

I know it's not conventional, so I'm not looking for somebody to tell me it's not conventional. Is this possible in theory? Difficult to do or fairly straightforward. How would I start? Thanks

Comment: UISafariViewController or WKWebView is probably what you're looking for. You can present the login page in-app, and when the user logs in, leave the web view and go to your app.

Comment: Yeah you can also build UIViewController having a UIWebView. Load your request in this controller and handle all the request and responses in the UIWebView delegate methods. Once this is a success, do whatever you want to do on a successful login or failed login attempt.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. So that points me in the right direction, and it sounds like it's possible. So, proceed I shall. Much appreciated.